# For and a period of time

Tags: grammar

As I know, we could use “for” with perfect tense to talk about a period of time. However, I am still not sure how to use “for”.

Could you tell me which sentence below is okay? I don't know I should use only one "for" or two "for"."

I have been waiting **for a bus 20 minutes.**

I have been waiting **for a bus for 20 minutes.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are acceptable. Both, however, are a little awkward.

- The first makes use of the quite ordinary expression

  > I have been waiting 20 minutes.

  *For* is not necessary; the semantics of the verb *wait* make it perfectly clear what role *20 minutes* plays in the sentence. But when you put *for a bus* between the verb and the time expression, the connection is broken; it takes a few microseconds of extra mental processing to figure out what role *20 minutes* plays.
- The second runs you up against what linguists call *horror aequi*—we don’t like using similar constructions too close to each other. ***For*** X **for** Y just *feels* uncomfortable. (This is a cross-language phenomenon and is probably what raised your question in the first place.)

The solution is very simple—flip your two adjunct phrases:

> I have been waiting 20 minutes for the bus.